# Difference between Db files for database from sys.master_file and msdb.dbo.backupfile for Backup

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries with me.
One pulls the below columns from the msdb.dbo.backupfile by backupset_uuid by joining backup_set_id with backupset table.

Other pulls the same columns from the sys.filegroups and sys.databases based on the database name.

With my current setup, for a backupset and the database, I get the same primary and log files as output. I want to know if there is any possibility where for a database the db files will be different from the database files that i get for the backupset.
Steps to create such database and backups will be helping. Kindly note the database is in restoring mode.

Also I noted that the state of file in the first case(backupset based) in Online mode as filtered but in second case(database name) the state of files is Restoring. Is it dependent on when the entires are created?

```
SELECT 
col1,
col2,
col3,
col4,
col5,
col6,
FROM msdb.dbo.backupfile bf 
JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bs 
ON bf.backup_set_id = bs.backup_set_id 
WHERE bf.state = 0 
AND bs.backup_set_uuid = '.....'
```

For database:

```
SELECT md.col1, md.col2, md.col3, md.col4,
md.col5, f.col6
FROM sys.filegroups f RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT m.col1, m.col2, m.col3, m.col4, m.col5
FROM sys.master_files m JOIN sys.databases d ON m.database_id = d.database_id WHERE d.name = '...') AS md
ON md.data_space_id = f.data_space_id;
```

Comment: Cross-post from [so] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69933335/difference-between-db-files-for-database-from-sys-master-file-and-msdb-dbo-backu

Comment: Please only tag the correct version, I can't imagine you are using three versions at once. And [tag:ssms] is not relevant here, as that is just an IDE